# Duplicate declaration in react native

Tags: react-native

By mistake, I use CheckBox as a project name. I generate the `React Native` project using `react-native init CheckBox`. I need check box for multiple choice question. So, I install the check box library from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-checkbox). Then, i import the library using `import CheckBox from 'react-native-checkbox';`. Now the problem: `Duplication declaration "CheckBox"`. What do i need to solve this ? Either I delete the project and generate new one. Or there is any way to solve this issue in current project ?
My code is :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import CheckBox from 'react-native-checkbox';

class CheckBox extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native!
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('CheckBox', () => CheckBox);
```

Answer (score 1):

`import SomethingElse from 'react-native-checkbox';`

From my understanding, we can rename the import name which is come from the export default of a package, ex. 'react-native-checkbox.

Therefore just change the component name from react-native-checkbox to something else of **CheckBox** then it should solve the Duplication declaration problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're importing a component called `CheckBox` and then defining a new component with the same name. To fix this you'll need to rename your component that you define:

```
class CustomCheckBox extends Component
...
AppRegistry.registerComponent('CustomCheckBox', () => CustomCheckBox)
```

Comment: Defining a new component like CustomCheckBox gives error "Application CheckBox has not been registered. This is either due to require() error during initialization or failure to call AppRegistry.registerComponent." I also make change at Appregistry.registerComponent(....).

Comment: Probably because you forgot to alter the `AppRegistry` call. Try killing your packager, making that change, and re-building.